# How can I organize a large number of Stringtemplate files into different folders

Tags: java, stringtemplate

In my project, I am using StringTemplate files to generate java code **extensively**. **I am keeping all StringTemplate files in one folder**. Now, I want to group StringTemplate files according to their category into different folders. I am using the following way to get instance of String template file.

```
StringTemplate templateOfSensorDriver = group.getInstanceOf("sensordriver");
// In this code, I am getting instance of sensordriver.st file 
  using getInstanceOf() method.
```

Can you please suggest me how can I give path of specific folder using getInstaceOf() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using StringTemplate 4, you can qualify your template names. The `STGroupDir` group will change the path to folders.

```
group.getInstanceOf("path/to/sensordriver");
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Can you please provide a detail link for this?